# Why is my Weeping Cherry tree growing like a bush?

Tags: trees, tree-care

2 years ago, I planted a Weeping Cherry tree (it was about 1 ft tall when I planted it). It doesn't seem to be growing taller, but it IS growing wide. It is growing kind of like a Japanese Lace Leaf Maple. I grew up with a Weeping Cherry in our yard and always loved it...however this doesn't appear to be normal, to me. Is this to be expected? Is there something I should do to correct how it is growing? Any help would be awesomely appreciated![image: ![Weeping Cherry tree growing like a bush]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7clW.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your weeping cherry is grafted onto a rootstock that was about a foot or two tall. I've worked with such "trees", and in my experience the rootstock never grows taller after grafting. You were actually sold a shrub-form weeping cherry, not a tree-form (in which the rootstock would've been about six feet tall or more at the graft). There is nothing that you can do to make a tree out of the shrub-form that you have.

If you have the room, you could create a large-ish garden bed around the shrub and add more shrubs, some perennials, maybe a very large rock or two, and perhaps a bench. Properly landscaped, this could result in a rather spectacular garden. If you don't have the room, maybe create a bed just for the weeping cherry, perhaps about four feet in diameter larger than the shrub is now to allow for future growth.